# How to remove a specific section of a string after the last occurrence of a specific character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, split

I have one string

```
"Opportunity >> Source = Email >> Status = New >> Branch = Mumbai"
```

Now, I want to chop off above string from last occurrence of `>>`. I mean, I want the result string should be like this

```
"Opportunity >> Source = Email >> Status = New"
```

Now, I am using various jquery/javascript functions like `split()`, `reverse()`, `join()`, `indexOf()` to remove the rest of the string from the last occurrence of `>>`, like this

```
var test = "Opportunity >> Source = Email >> Status = New >> Branch = Mumbai";
var count = test.split("").reverse().join("").indexOf('>>');
var string = test.substring(0, test.length - count-2);
```

Using this, I am able to get the desired result. But I assume there must be some other easier way than this to achieve this using jquery/javascript.

Comment: Thank you everyone, all answers are correct, but I will choose one which is simple and  I can understand easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) method of String

```js
var input = "Opportunity >> Source = Email >> Status = New >> Branch = Mumbai";

console.log( input.substring(0, input.lastIndexOf( ">>" )) )
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
"Opportunity >> Source = Email >> Status = New >> Branch = Mumbai".split(" >> ").slice(0, -1).join(" >> ")
```

```js
var str = "Opportunity >> Source = Email >> Status = New >> Branch = Mumbai";
console.log(str.split(" >> ").slice(0, -1).join(" >> "));
```

Comment: The `(0,-1)` isn't obvious, but nicely keeps the code on one line.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the lastindex of `>>` and then get substring from beginning of string to last position of element `>>` in it :

```js
var str = "Opportunity >> Source = Email >> Status = New >> Branch = Mumbai"
 var lastindex = str.lastIndexOf(">>");
 if (lastindex  != -1){
    alert(str.substring(0, lastindex-1 )); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has lastIndexOf() method . You can find last occurance with it. Then remove rest of the string easily. 
Example:

```
var test = "Opportunity >> Source = Email >> Status = New >> Branch = Mumbai";
var finIndex = test.lastIndexOf('>>');
var string = test.substring(0, finIndex);
```

You can check link [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can `splice` it off:

```
var arr = test.split(">>");
arr = arr.splice(arr.length - 1, 1);
string = test.join(">>");
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option: use `pop()`

```
var src = "Opportunity >> Source = Email >> Status = New >> Branch = Mumbai"

var arr = src.split(">>");
arr.pop();
var s = arr.join(">>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex in [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to removing extra part of string. Regex select last part of string (`>> Branch = Mumbai`) and repalace it with empty. You can see it in [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dT9mK5/1)

```js
var text = "Opportunity >> Source = Email >> Status = New >> Branch = Mumbai";
console.log(text.replace(/>>[^>]+$/g, ""));
```

Comment: Yeah, it is also simple, but I am not good with regex, it would be much better if you explain your regex little bit.